# Running meteor on android device Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm following this tutorial on how to create an app for android device: http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp/

I'm at the layout step at the moment, the app runs perfect on browser in chrome but when I run `meteor run android-device` on my android device I just see a blank screen and when I go to `chrome://inspect` and inspect the device I get these errors:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try add `App.accessRule('*');` into your `mobile-config.js` file.